Postgresql calculate SUM value in time for all items in a table with gaps
I would like to calculate SUM value in time for all items in a table "measures", which contains measures from stations (each one defined with an identifier)
_ id_station (varchar)
_ measure_time (timestamp)
_ measure_value (float)

My goal is to create a graph of the sum for all stations measures in time (1 sum for each day with at least 1 measure of 1 station)
The issue is that stations are not synchronized and to calculate the sum for each day of the year, I need to take for each station the closest value in the past.
How to solve this?
Many thanks.

Please consider following these suggestions.

Take a look at the date_bin() function. That's what you need to put in the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks, I will check that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Kindly construct a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with your table(s), sample data and a desired result!

Thanks everybody for your help. I'm working on water volume time series for several reservoirs, to monitor evolution of the available water stock (globally)
Measures for each station, recorded in the database are not synchronized : each station can have a different update rate)
What I want to obtain is to merge (SUM) the different time series to plot the global water stock. The problem: for a specific date, we can have only one measure from one station, and another day we can have another one. The chart must for each date on the timeline, get the latest value for each station.
